# Vim: run some command when editing specific file

Tags: vim

I want my Vim to run some commands, such as `setlocal spell spelllang=en_us` when I edit a file with extension of `en`, e.g. `abc.en`. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    augroup spell_settings
        au!
" set en_us as default language (unknown extension):
        au BufEnter * setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
" set en_us for en files specifically:
        au BufEnter *.en  setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
" to add multiple commands just append:
        au BufEnter *.en  setlocal syntax on
    augroup END
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It can wok! But what can I do if I want to run more than one command for en file? such as syntax on. I prefer to make the en file as a new filetype, but I don't know how to tell vim to run some commands when it's editing new file type